# PHP pbkdf2 result not the same as C# rfc2898derivebytes

Tags: c#, php

I'm trying to decrypt my C# encrypted content in php, I'm doing this in steps so I can keep track of everything. I'm starting out with the key and the iv.

My C# code:

```
        string PKey = "12345678";
        string salt = "C326EBD1113438B1715AB1B5A1817";
        byte[] bytesKey = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(PKey);
        bytesKey = SHA256.Create().ComputeHash(bytesKey);

        textBox4.Text = Convert.ToBase64String(bytesKey); //hash

        byte[] saltBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(salt);
        var key = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(bytesKey, saltBytes, 1000);

        byte[] keyKey = key.GetBytes(256 / 8);
        byte[] ivKey = key.GetBytes(128 / 8);

        textBox5.Text = Convert.ToBase64String(keyKey); //key
        textBox6.Text = Convert.ToBase64String(ivKey); //iv
```

My PHP code:

```
$pass = "12345678";
$newpass = "";
$salt = "C326EBD1113438B1715AB1B5A1817";
$hasher = "SHA1";
$iterations = 1000;
$keysize = 256;
$ivsize = 128;

$newpass = hash("sha256",mb_convert_encoding($pass,"UTF-8"),true);


$out = hash_pbkdf2($hasher, $newpass, $salt, $iterations, ($keysize+$ivsize)/8, true);

$key = substr($out, 0, $keysize/8);
$iv = substr($out, $ivsize/8);


echo "hash: " .base64_encode($newpass);
echo "<br>";
echo "key: " . base64_encode($key);
echo "<br>";
echo "iv: " . base64_encode($iv);
```

After experimenting with pretty much everything, these are the best results that I could get:

C#:

```
hash: 73l8gRjwLftklgfdXT+MdiMEjJwGPVMsyVxe16iYpk8=
key: WOqyVBejGMkYIwO0OafALN+U4qBBwM7sVQtlyXpPwyo=
iv: F8jyzVIGdVlIwP/IlkfPFg==
```

PHP:

```
hash: 73l8gRjwLftklgfdXT+MdiMEjJwGPVMsyVxe16iYpk8=
key: WOqyVBejGMkYIwO0OafALN+U4qBBwM7sVQtlyXpPwyo=
iv: 35TioEHAzuxVC2XJek/DKhfI8s1SBnVZSMD/yJZHzxY=
```

As you can see, only the iv if actually different, the hash and key are the same.

Does anyone know why just the iv is different?

UPDATE:

replacing base64_encode($iv); with base64_encode(mb_convert_encoding($iv,"UTF-8"));

Gives me this iv:
35Q/QT8/P1ULZT96Tz8qFz8/P1IGdVlIPz/Ilkc/Fg==

If I'm not mistaken, this contains parts of the C# iv...

Comment: Are you talking about encryption or hashing? I don't know what's going on here, but rolling your own PBKDF2 function is bound to be really, really bad news.

Comment: I haven't added the encryption part yet as I'm converting it to php in steps so it's easier to track issues, the PBKDF2 function was taken from here: https://defuse.ca/php-pbkdf2.htm

Comment: And it's just returning hash_pbkdf2 anyway so I removed it from my post

Comment: It would probably be better to use an [actual crypto library like Sodium](https://github.com/jedisct1/libsodium-php) than something cribbed from a blog post in your code.